# Can finitely many values of a polynomial determine it?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer greater than 2. Define an equivalence relation on monic integer polynomials of degree $d$: $f\sim g \iff f(k_1 x+k_2)=g(k_3 x+k_4)$ for some integers $k_1,...,k_4$.

> Is there a number $m$ such that for any $m$ distinct integers, there is at most one equivalence class that attains these at integer coordinates?

I ask for $d>2$ since it is vacuous for $d=1$ (only one class) and it fails for $d=2$: $x^2-1$ and $2y^2$ are not in the same class and having infinitely many common values.

From some short calculations I think it is true that for $d+1$ (maybe a bit more) distinct values there are at most a finite number of equivalence classes possible, but I don't see how to bound the number of classes uniformly, let alone by 1.

Comment: Does $k$ depend on $f$ and $g$?


Comment: @darij:  based on his example I think he means just outputs, and no given inputs to be paired with them, though I don't claim this changes much if anything.

Comment: So assume you have found your $m$. Take some polynomial $f$ of degree $d$, and let $f(2)$, $f(4)$, $f(6)$, ..., $f(2m)$ be your $m$ integers (for most $f$ they will indeed be distinct). How can you prevent them from being attained by $f(2x)$ as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "one equivalence class that attains these"? Could you give a formal definition? 

Comment: OK, now that you allowed affine transformations, I choose $m$ integers $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_m$ which can be written both as values of $x^2-1$ and as values of $2y^2$. And I take $f(p_1)$, ..., $f(p_m)$. These are values of the polynomial $f(x^2-1)$ and of the polynomial $f(2x^2)$. Where is your god now?

Comment: @Kevin: a polynomial $f$ attains a value $y$ if there is an integer $x$ with $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @darij: thanks! true. last edit, I promise: now the polynomials are monic.

Comment: In this case I can prove that 2 values of a monic quadratic are enough to determine a finite set of possible candidates.

Comment: @Dror: but what does it mean for an equivalence class to attain a set of values? Is this a valid restating of the problem: ``Fix $d>2$. Is there an $m$ such that ``Given any $y_1,\dots,y_m$, there is a unique class of polynomials that has a representative $f$ such that there are $x_1,\dots,x_m$ with $f(x_i)=y_i$.''?

Comment: This is becoming interesting ;) Let $u$ be a big number with over $9000$ different representations in the form $x^2+y^2$ (with $x$ and $y$ integers). Then, the polynomials $x^2$ and $u-x^2$ have many common values, and by composing them with an even-degree polynomial, you get two monic polynomials with many common values. They should not be affine-equivalent.

Comment: @darij: great! that solves even degree. now for odd...

Comment: There are numbers with many representations as a sum of two cubes.

Comment: @Boris, indeed, Theorem 412 in Hardy and Wright states that, whatever $r$, there are numbers that are representable as sums of two positive cubes in at least $r$ different ways. 

Comment: @Boris: that makes degree divisible by 3 (but not exactly 3) work. What about 3 and the rest of odd numbers? Anticipating trouble, simply prime degrees?

Comment: It is widely believed, but not proved, that no (non-zero) integer can be written as a sum of two 5th powers in two different ways. 

Comment: @Dror: how does this help? You want a monic polynomial...

Comment: @Darij: Sum of two cubes is the same as difference of two cubes, so every $a^3+b^3=u$ given another solution $(-a,b)$ to $f(x^3)=f(y^3-u)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking for a condition on $f$ and $g$ such that the curve:
$$C: f(y) - g(x) = 0$$
has a uniformly bounded number of rational points.
Note that if $f$ and $g$ are equivalent under an affine transformation,
then $C$ is divisible by a linear factor and is not reducible. The converse is
*almost* true. Namely, as long as the degree of $f$ and $g$ is sufficiently
large, and $f$ and $g$ are not of the form
$a \circ b$ for polynomials $a$ and $b$ of degree $> 1$,
then $C$ will be irreducible. (This follows from CFSG. Of course, using composition of functions
one can create many degenerate examples: $P(y)^2 - Q(x)^2$ is divisible
by $P(y) - Q(x)$. The example in the comments giving a example
in even degrees arises in this way, by taking a degree two example
and using composition.)
If the degree $d$ of $f$ (and $g$) is prime, then $f$ and $g$
are certainly indecomposable, so let's concentrate on that case, since there
are no reductions to smaller degree. For convenience, let's also only consider
the case when $C$ is irreducible (if $d$ is prime, this is automatic if $d$ is
sufficiently large, by the remark above.)

If $C$ has genus at least two, then $C$ will have only finitely
many *rational* points (Faltings). Work of
Caporaso, Harris, and Mazur:

http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1997-10-01/S0894-0347-97-00195-1/home.html

suggests that the number of solutions may be even be bounded in terms of the genus, and hence in terms of the degree.
Whether you believe Lang's conjectures or not, you are unlikely to disprove
Lang's conjectures easily, so any negative example to your claim should come from 
a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ so that $C$ has small genus.

In small genus, we may have many rational points, but as far as integral points
we also have Siegel's theorem to content with. A projective model
$\widetilde{C}$ of $C$
is given by $Z^d f(Y/Z) - Z^d g(X/Z) = 0$. Setting $Z = 0$, we obtain the equation
"at infinity"
$Y^d - X^d = 0$, which has $d$ points over the complex numbers.  Hence, assuming $d \ge 3$,
$$\# \widetilde{C} \setminus C \ge 3.$$
 By Siegel's theorem we deduce 
$C$ has only finitely many integral solutions.  Thus, when the degree $d$ is
prime and sufficiently large (or more generally, providing one avoids degeneracies arising from the phenomena alluded to in the first paragraph), any $f$ and $g$ in different equivalence classes
will only coincide on a fixed number of integers.

Your question, however, asks whether there is a uniform bound. There
is certainly no uniform bound for Siegel's theorem, at least when the genus
is $\le 1$.
 There is a standard “renomalization” trick which takes
a curve with infinitely many rational points and produces a curve with many
integral points. This trick works in this case. 
Specifically, suppose that $C: f(y) - g(x) = 0$ has infinitely
many rational points. Then there certainly exists some integer 
 $N$ such that $C$
has a bizillion points of the form $(u/N,v/N)$ (take $N$ to be a common denominator).  We may then write down the different integral
model:
$$C': N^d f(y/N) - N^d g(x/N) = 0,$$
which now has a bizillion *integral* points $(u,v)$. This also allows one to answer your question in general degrees, simply by choosing $f$ and $g$ so that $C$ has
infinitely many rational points, and then renomalizing appropriately.
The easiest specific example would be to take $C$ of genus zero. 
For example, take $f = t^n$ and $g = t^{n-1}(t-1)$.
Then 
$C: f(y) - g(x) = y^n - x^{n-1}(x-1)$ has genus zero, as can be seen from the 
parametrization
$$x  = \frac{1}{1 - t^n}, \qquad y = \frac{t}{1 - t^n}.$$
From the above construction, there will exist positive integers $N$ such that
the polynomials $t^n$ and $t^{n-1}(t - N)$ will take on the same bizillion values.
This answers your question in the negative.

EDIT: I guess the last example can be made quite concrete.
Let 
$$N = (1 - 2^d)(1 - 3^d)(1 - 4^d) \ldots (1 - M^d).$$
Then $t^d$ and $t^{d-1}(t-N)$ both take on the values
$\displaystyle{\left(\frac{aN}{1 - a^d} \right)^d}$
for $a = 2, \ldots, M$.

Comment: What is CFSG  ?

Comment: Google says it's the China Fire and Security Group, also Community Financial Services Group, Combat Flight Simulator Group, ...., but here I suspect it's the Classification of Finite Simple Groups. 

Comment: Dear Esperantist, do you know a reference for the statement involving the CFSG?  I have been thinking about related problems and would be really interested in reading something on this.  Thanks!

Comment: So if I were to confine the question even further to "primitive" polynomials, in the sense that they are not the composition of polynomials of smaller degree, then Lang's conjectures imply a uniform bound?

Comment: @Esperantist: thank you very much for the reference! You do bring hope... ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. $f(x)$ and $f(2x)$ will not be in the same equivalence class in general, yet their images will agree on infinitely many points. Hence there is no *fixed* value $m$ such that any $m$ points determine a single equivalence class

Comment: ahhhhh. now that's true. then let's go all the way to all affine transformations!

Comment: I don't get it. Did you mean to write $f(x) = g(ax+k)$? But even then you get more examples via $f(x)$ and $g(h(x))$ for polynomials $h$ of degree $> 1$. Or do I misunderstand the problem completely?

Comment: Degree is fixed.